# Linking to other div from div in same page

Tags: php, html

I've found this script somewhere on this forum and it works fine. Unless you want to make use of folders in the backend. Then it's not working fine any more. So now my root folder is building files... Can someone look at this script and help me out? I'm not so used to PHP and MySQL but learning... ;-)

```
<div id="content">
    <?php 
    // All the page files, the first being the default value

    $pages=array('page1','page2','page3','page4','page5','page6', 'page7', 'page8');

    // Read $page variable from query string '?p='

    $page=isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:$pages[0];

    // Check if value of $page is allowed, assign default if not

    if(!in_array($page,$pages))
    {
        $page=$pages[0];
    }
    include($page . '.php'); 
    ?>
</div>
```

Within the header the links are formed like;

```
<a href="index.php?p=page1"></a>
```

This all works fine! But if you change this last code in;

```
<a href="start.php?p=chapters/page1"></a>
```

It won't work any more...

Please help...!

Answer (score -1):

Just add `chapters/` to the include path:

```
include('chapters/' . $page . '.php');
```

And keeping your HTML same:

```
<a href="index.php?p=page1"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!

So I changed the script below to as you proposed:

$pages=array('chapters/page1','page2','page3','page4','page5','page6', 
But it didn't work out as expected...

I now get an error 404...

any clues?

Comment: @EazyEagle Please look at my answer again. Also, take a look at your link tag

Comment: this works... Thank you very much! I have to clean my root folder now, but I am happy!

Comment: Sorry, I was called away for some business... That's why I'm late with my reply!

Comment: @EazyEagle If this answer was helpful, please upvote or select this as best answer